# Verilog help: .V to schematic

Tags: verilog

I trying to see what is going on in this .v file to learn (need visual).
Could any one help with terminology:

- What is a Verilog schematic called?
- What is a Verilog schematic viewer called?

Could anyone refer an application to view/convert .V as a graphic
(logic gates, not block diagrams)?

**This** [image]

**Not this** [image: block diagram]

I would like something that is not an ISE (all the ones I found were 20GB or more; too large).

Comment: 'Verilog schematic' -- You maybe looking for netlist viewer...Netlist generated after synthesis incorporates standard cells from libraries, Standard cells are typically represented as 'black boxes' in any standard synthesiser tool with inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog doesn't describe a circuit of logic gate as you want it. That's *one* possible mapping of a subset of Verilog functionality.

But in general, verilog literally just describes the netlist as a graph of abstract logical operations, as you show in your "not this" example.

The conversion of that to something that is composed of the basic logic gates that you might know is complex, and not unique. It's the "technology mapping" step that sits in between writing verilog and bringing it to hardware, quite far in the back.

After that mapping, that still just yields an abstract graph of connected nodes, you need to lay it out as "readable" schematic. That's actually the place and route problem! So, that's literally the last step in converting verilog to hardware.

It will *not* help you understand what you're doing in verilog, because it's the last, condensed down, step in a series of optimizing steps.

So, what you want could exist as the result of a verilog workflow not targetting an FPGA or an ASIC process, but "schematic sheet composed of logic gates as bteddy1 knows them". But looking at that would tell you as much about your verilog as looking at the micrococode in your server CPU could tell you about the Python you've written: not much at all, unless you're really already an expert in the nitty-gritties of how that conversion happens.